# Android + ORMLite + java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have an Android project which uses ORMLite. All works fine, but for some fields in database it uses `java.sql.Timestamp` as field type. It worked fine on ORMLite 4.10, which I used before. But now I need to update ORMLite, and have a problem..
When I updated ORMLite to newer version and run it, app throws exception:

```
W/System.err(  615): java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite can't store unknown class
    class java.sql.Timestamp for field 'createDate'.
    Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

There was no dataType parameter for createDate field before. But when I added it, error is not fixed and app throws this exception too :(.  The project is already on Market, so I can't change dataType to other type (such as Date), and can remove this field too.

What should I use for Timestamp on newer ORMLite? Or it is ORMLite bug?

**UPDATE:**
Fixed it by changing Timestamp type to Serializable type. Now code looks like this:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
public Serializable createDate;

public Timestamp getCreateDate()
{
    return (Timestamp)createDate;
}
```

Comment: For posterity, you should _not_ have to do that `Serializable` hack.  You should be able to have any type that implements `Serializable` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about this @st1ing.  This certainly can be a bug in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) but I suspect rather that it may be an incompatibility.  In version 4.14, we had to make a change how `Serializable` fields are handled.  [Upgrade notes](http://ormlite.com/docs/4.14) are online.  To quote:

> In addition, serialized types must also now specify their dataType value. You should use `DataType.SERIALIZABLE` to continue to store serialized objects in the database. This will allow us to add direct support for other serialized types in the future without breaking backwards compatibility.
>
> If you already have `Serializable` data (`byte[]` or other objects) stored in a database then you will need to add something like the following to your fields:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
Serializable field;
```

Actually, the exception is trying to give you a hint as to how to fix you problem:

```
Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

So try adding that to your `Timestamp` field.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried to add dataType, but it don't work :( I added @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE) to field, but it still throws SQLexception from my original message. I also tried to use other dataTypes, but nothing helps...