# Using ORMLite config file: java.sql.SQLException: Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE

Tags: android, ormlite, sqlexception

I'm trying to use a generated class (generated using the Google App Engine) in my Android application through ORMLite. I've created a config file as follows:

```
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.name.app.entities.customerendpoint.model.Customer
tableName=customer
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=key
generatedId=false
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=firstName
#columnName=lastClickDate
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=lastName
#indexName=clickcount_name_idx
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=email
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=postcode
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=birthDate
dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
#foreign=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=gender
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=facebookId
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=googleId
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=pictureUrl
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=verificationCode
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
```

In the constructor of my DBHelper I'm referring to this file:
`super(context, "APP", null, 1, R.raw.ormlite_config);`

Unfortenately, when I'm creating the table an SQLException is raised:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite can't store unknown class class com.google.api.client.util.DateTime for field 'birthDate'. Serializable fields must specify dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

The weird thing is I definitely specified the birthDate field to be Serializable:

```
fieldName=birthDate
dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong or is it a bug in ORMLite?

Comment: Here are similar problems:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862372/ormlite-datatype-datatype-serializable-doesnt-work   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186705/android-ormlite-java-sql-timestamp

Comment: I've already read those problems before posting mine but those questions involve annotations, they just forgot to set the datatype. I'm not using annotations and I didn't forget to set the datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist datatype by `dataPersister=SERIALIZABLE`, instead `dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE` in your config file.