# How to store byte[] in ORMLite Android?

Tags: ormlite, android-orm

This may be a duplicate question but none of the previous answer could work for me.
I am trying to store the byte[] in ormlite but I am getting following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite does not know how to store class [B for field 'imageBytes'. byte[] fields must specify dataType=DataType.BYTE_ARRAY or SERIALIZABLE
```

I am have already added field type as dataType=DataType.BYTE_ARRAY in java class and in config file also.
Here is my Java class.

```
public class ImageData {

    @DatabaseField
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
    byte[] imageBytes;

    public ImageData() {
    }

    public ImageData(long id, byte[] imageBytes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imageBytes = imageBytes;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public byte[] getImageBytes() {
        return imageBytes;
    }

    public void setImageBytes(byte[] imageBytes) {
        this.imageBytes = imageBytes;
    }
    public void saveImage(DatabaseHelper dbHelper) throws java.sql.SQLException{
        Dao<ImageData,Long> dao = dbHelper.getImageDataDao();
        dao.createOrUpdate(this);
    }
    public static ImageData getImage(DatabaseHelper dbHelper,long id)throws java.sql.SQLException{
        Dao<ImageData,Long> dao = dbHelper.getImageDataDao();
        ImageData obj = dao.queryForId(id);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And here is my ormlite_config.txt file contents.

```
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.sample.model.ImageData
tableName=imageData
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
generatedId=true
allowGeneratedIdInsert=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=imageBytes
dataPersister = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
```

I used `dataPersister` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258697/using-ormlite-config-file-java-sql-sqlexception-serializable-fields-must-speci). Instead of dataPersister I have tried dataType also in my config file. I am not able find the solution. Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you sure that you've updated your ormlite_config.txt file?  This feels like the data-persister is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

> I used dataPersister as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26360093/179850). Instead of dataPersister I have tried dataType also in my config file.

That answer specifically says that you should use `dataPersister = BYTE_ARRAY` *not* `DataType.BYTE_ARRAY`.  Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I tried dataPersister = BYTE_ARRAY also but got same error .